# Infopath concat function email URL breaks at first %20

Tags: infopath, list-form, encode

I am working on an InfoPath form that has the ability to select a button that will open an email.

The email script is done in a concat function. In the function text is the URL to where the form is located in sharepoint.  The URL for the form has white spaces.  I use the % encoding to represent the white spaces - `%20`.  When the email comes up the URL stops at the first %20 (white space).

Example:

concat code:

```
concat("mailto:","http://www-c-hhj.ilu.llou.edu/SE/CPE/CPE%20Forms/G5%20rtn%20high/good%20break"
```

Looks like this in the email:

```
http://www-c-hhj.ilu.llou.edu/SE/CPE/CPE Forms/G5 rtn high/good break
```

How do I avoid the URL from "breaking"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by testing different characters.  The key point i did not realize was that the "%20" in the URL name is literal and does not represent a white space for the URL.  There is no whitespace in the URL string.  To use the "%20" as a literal string I needed to code it as %2520 so that the resulting string would include the %20 in the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

If the mail client is MS Outlook - you can put the link inside < > characters, then Outlook will generate the link of the full string including the spaces.

Ex:
concat("mailto:?&subject=&subject=Follow-up%20Note%20"; Title; "&body=Dear%20Colleague%0D%0DPlease....%20<http://urlbase/"; Title; ".xml>")